# UIView with text edit fields

Tags: ios, ios5

my view starts with a focus on a text editor, which causes the keyboard to pop up. I'd like to avoid that, making users tap the text field before the keyboard pops up.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting the text field as the firstResponder (ie, using [textView becomeFirstResponder]) somewhere in the code? If so, you don't need to do that - that will happen automatically when you tap the text field.

Comment: Yep. i was setting it as firstResponder. when removed it stopped going into editing mode automatically. this is what I need. thanks. Will tag your response in 8 minutes...